# Android Studio - SSLHandshakeException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm new to Java/PHP programming and I've tried to find the solution to this (probably simple) fix but I've come up nil. I've checked the Android Developer article on problems with SSL [https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#CommonProblems] but that hasn't seemed to solve any of the problems I've been facing so far.

**EDIT:** This has now been resolved, apparently I forgot to remove the 'S' from 'HTTPS' meaning it was trying to access a secure SSL connection, which I obviously did not have.

The error also includes:

```
2022-01-23 15:56:27.925 413-1117/? E/audit: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=5704 uid=10342 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c86,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

And the full exception error is displayed as a toast message during running the application:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I'm trying to access the MySQL PHP of https://192.168.0.159/LoginRegister/signup.php (localhost) via signup.java.

I've also tried adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"  along with` along with `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the Android Manifest and the certificate.crt/network_security_config.xml in the raw folder and XML folder respectively as per the Android Developer article.

My current *Android Gradle Plugin Version is 7.0.4* and my *Gradle Version is 7.2* (I've tried changing the versions of both).

If you require any more information regarding the project just let me know.

Thanks a ton,

Brandon.

Comment: Working with self signed certificates can be a hassle.  Consider purchasing a cert from a well known provider such as DigiCert.

Answer (score 5):

As you have already mentioned, you don't have a SSL certificate to access `https` for I'm assuming, your `localhost` ip address.

If you are already using `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest, changing the `https` to `http` should make things work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer! I didn't realise how I could forget to remove a simple 'S' yet here we are. I would upvote your answer but my reputation is too low. Thanks a heap anyways! :)